# Hang up people to cause the anger of the Lord to turn

Tags: commentaries, parashat-balak

Could someone explain to me how the anger of the Lord is turned by hanging people in view for all to watch?

Numbers 25:4 (Mechon-mamre translation): "Take all the chiefs of the people, and hang them up unto the LORD in face of the sun, that the fierce anger of the LORD may turn away from Israel"

How does such an image reverse the anger of the Lord that flared up because of the sin of those who adventually would be hanged.

Answer (score 3):

See Rashi P' Beshalach 14:4:

> ואכבדה בפרעה. כְּשֶׁהַקָּבָּ"ה מִתְנַקֵּם בָּרְשָׁעִים שְׁמוֹ
>   מִתְגַּדֵּל וּמִתְכַּבֵּד, וְכֵן הוּא אוֹמֵר "וְנִשְׁפַּטְתִּי אִתּוֹ
>   וְגוֹ'" וְאַחַר כָּךְ "וְהִתְגַדִּלְתִּי וְהִתְקַדִּשְׁתִּי
>   וְנוֹדַעְתִּי וְגוֹ'" (יחזקאל ל"ח), וְאוֹמֵר "שָׁמָּה שִׁבַּר רִשְׁפֵי
>   קָשֶׁת", וְאַחַר כָּךְ "נוֹדָע בִּיהוּדָה אֱלֹהִים" (תהלים ע"ו),
>   וְאוֹמֵר "נוֹדַע ה' מִשְׁפָּט עָשָׂה" (שם ט'):
>
> ואכבדה בפרעה AND I WILL BE HONOURED THROUGH PHARAOH — When the Holy
>   One, blessed be He, takes vengeance on the wicked His name is
>   magnified and honoured. Thus, too, it states, (Ezekiel 38:22, 23) “And
>   I will plead against him [with pestilence and with blood etc.]”, and
>   afterwards, “Thus I shall be magnified and sanctified etc.” And it
>   states, (Psalms 76:3) “There He broke the fiery shafts of the bow”,
>   and afterwards (after He has done this) (v. 2) “In Judah is God known.
>   “Further it states, (Psalms 9:17) “The Lord is known because He
>   executeth judgment” (Mekhilta d'Rabbi Yishmael 14:4:2).

Since when Hashem takes vengeance on the wicked His name is magnified and honored, This also appeases the anger of Hashem, which came about through the *chilul Hashem* caused by the sinners.

Answer (score 0):

we find in novi ,by the givvonimm
they requested revenge for what the
king did to them....
the jews hung the king’s grandchildren
and left them hanging for all (עולי רגלים)to see

due to hashem anger at the chilull
hashem caused by the king

also....
another place we find hanging
appeasing the wrath of hashem
is by the hanging of HAMAN

gemara says : “vachamas hamelech
shachacha “ refers to hashem
and explains the sfas emess
because they create problems even
up there
therefore his hanging in full glory
appeases the anger

Comment: I'm not sure I follow how this answers the question. Nor do I really understand what you're saying.

Comment: Are you saying that God's anger can be cool the same way that the Givvonimm lust for revenge can be cool?

Comment: alaychem.      it was not done for the givoynim.    they were hung and left hanging (lava of bal tollin)to alleviate the anger of hashem

Comment: No. Please read the verses carefully. The Givvonimm asked the hanging, it was not God's demand or David idea to cool God's anger. If the Givvonimm  would choose a different compensation, it would get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

The rest of the people are showing that they vehemently disagree with the sinners. I.e. the poor habits are no longer "contagious" and being emulated.